# Do python recursive calls interfere with each other?

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to set up a recursive game solver (for the cracker-barrel peg game). The recursive function appears to not be operating correctly, and some outputs are created with no trace of how they were created (despite logging all steps). Is it possible that the python recursion steps are overwriting eachother?

I have already tried adding in print statements at all steps of the way. The game rules and algorithms work correctly, but the recursive play algorithm is not operating as expected

```
def recursive_play(board, moves_list, move_history, id, first_trial, recurse_counter):
    # Check how many moves are left
    tacks_left = len(char_locations(board, character=tack, grid=True))
    log_and_print(f"tacks_left: {tacks_left}")
    log_and_print(f"moves_left: {len(moves_list)}")
    log_and_print(f"moves_list: {moves_list}")

    if (len(moves_list) == 0):
        if (tacks_left == 1):
            # TODO: Remove final move separator
            log_and_print(f"ONE TACK LEFT :)!!!!")
            log_and_print(f"move_history to retrun for win: {move_history}")
            return move_history
        pass
    elif (len(moves_list) > 0):
        # Scan through all moves and make them recursively
        for move in moves_list:
            if first_trial:
                id += 1
            else:
                # id += 1
                id = id
            next_board = make_move(board, move)
            next_moves = possible_moves(next_board)
            if first_trial:
                next_history = "START: " + move
            else:
                next_history = move_history + round_separator + move

            # log_and_print(f"og_board:")
            prettify_board(board)
            log_and_print(f"move: {move}")
            log_and_print(f"next_board:")
            prettify_board(next_board)
            # log_and_print(f"next_moves: {next_moves}")
            log_and_print(f"next_history: {next_history}")
            log_and_print(f"id: {id}")
            log_and_print(f"recurse_counter: {recurse_counter}")
            # NOTE: Would this be cleaner with queues?
            recursive_play(next_board, moves_list=next_moves, move_history=next_history, id=id, first_trial=False, recurse_counter=recurse_counter+1)

        log_and_print(f"finished scanning all moves for board: {board}")
```

I expect all steps to be logged, and "START" should only occur on the first trial. However, a mysterious "START" appears in a later step with no trace of how that board was created.

Good Output:

```
INFO:root:next_history: START: 4 to 2 to 1 , 6 to 5 to 4 , 1 to 3 to 6 , 7 to 4 to 2
INFO:root:id: 1
INFO:root:recurse_counter: 3
INFO:root:tacks_left: 5
INFO:root:moves_left: 2
INFO:root:moves_list: ['9 to 8 to 7', '10 to 6 to 3']
INFO:root:o---
INFO:root:xo--
INFO:root:oox-
INFO:root:xoox
INFO:root:move: 9 to 8 to 7
INFO:root:next_board:
INFO:root:o---
INFO:root:xo--
INFO:root:oox-
INFO:root:xoox
INFO:root:next_history: START: 4 to 2 to 1 , 6 to 5 to 4 , 1 to 3 to 6 , 7 to 4 to 2 , 9 to 8 to 7
INFO:root:id: 1
INFO:root:recurse_counter: 4
INFO:root:tacks_left: 4
INFO:root:moves_left: 1
INFO:root:moves_list: ['10 to 6 to 3']
INFO:root:o---
INFO:root:xx--
INFO:root:ooo-
INFO:root:xooo
INFO:root:move: 10 to 6 to 3
INFO:root:next_board:
INFO:root:o---
INFO:root:xx--
INFO:root:ooo-
INFO:root:xooo
INFO:root:next_history: START: 4 to 2 to 1 , 6 to 5 to 4 , 1 to 3 to 6 , 7 to 4 to 2 , 9 to 8 to 7 , 10 to 6 to 3
```

Bad Output:

```
INFO:root:move: 6 to 3 to 1
INFO:root:next_board:
INFO:root:x---
INFO:root:xo--
INFO:root:ooo-
INFO:root:oooo
INFO:root:next_history: START: 6 to 3 to 1
INFO:root:id: 2
INFO:root:recurse_counter: 0
INFO:root:tacks_left: 2
INFO:root:moves_left: 1
INFO:root:moves_list: ['1 to 2 to 4']
INFO:root:o---
INFO:root:oo--
INFO:root:xoo-
INFO:root:oooo
INFO:root:move: 1 to 2 to 4
INFO:root:next_board:
INFO:root:o---
INFO:root:oo--
INFO:root:xoo-
INFO:root:oooo
INFO:root:next_history: START: 6 to 3 to 1 , 1 to 2 to 4
INFO:root:id: 2
INFO:root:recurse_counter: 1
INFO:root:tacks_left: 1
INFO:root:moves_left: 0
INFO:root:moves_list: []
INFO:root:ONE TACK LEFT :)!!!!
INFO:root:move_history to retrun for win: START: 6 to 3 to 1 , 1 to 2 to 4
INFO:root:finished scanning all moves for board: ['o---', 'oo--', 'xoo-', 'oooo']
```

Any tips anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Here's my code, please debug it for me" questions tend to be too broad to be acceptable here. Can you extract a narrow, specific question about the Python language? See the [mcve] page in our Help Center, and the "Tricks for Trimming" section of http://sscce.org/.

Comment: ...that said, notice how you print the message implying that `first_trial==True` inside a loop? Are you sure your code hasn't returned out to the first call's stack frame, and thus returned to the context with that initial value?